# Clicking custom Notification button

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

This is my notification, i need event when clicking button on notification. 
setOnClickPendingIntent doesn't work for me.  R.layout.mynotification is under the code. (I don't want addAction).

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(Fragmentz.ctx, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(Fragmentz.ctx, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);

        // Build notification
        RemoteViews notificationView = new RemoteViews(Fragmentz.ctx.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.mynotification);

        Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(Fragmentz.ctx)
                .setContentTitle("Radio")
                .setContentText("").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_notif)
                .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                .build();


        noti.contentView = notificationView;
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) Fragmentz.ctx.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // hide the notification after its selected
        noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

R.layout.mynotification.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:text="Play"
        android:id="@+id/not_button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img_btn_play"
        android:background="@null"
        />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: See if my answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an intent through pendingIntent like so:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, desiredClass.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Notice the flag FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT and check if it is the right one for your case.

Comment: I am sorry, it doen't work. In my code i have already write it. i need button click event. android:id="@+id/not_button"

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

```
    // Creates an explicit intent for an ResultActivity to receive.
    Intent resultIntent =  new Intent(Fragmentz.ctx, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);

    // This ensures that the back button follows the recommended convention for the back key.
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(mContext);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: I don't need back button event. I have my own button on my notification layout. I need give a event for it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you

Add this line

```
Intent listener = new Intent(ctx, NotificationClickHandler.class);
PendingIntent pListener = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, listener, 0);
notificationView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.not_button, pListener);
```

And this in your manifest

```
<receiver android:name="com.xxx.NotificationClickHandler" /> // Use your package name
```

Finally create a Class `NotificationClickHandler`

```
public class NotificationClickHandler extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //TODO: do your desired work here
    }   
}
```

**Note:** Rather than `Activity` this can be done using `BroadcastReceiver` too.

Comment: Click doesn't work and i didn't get any error, i tried both activity and  BroadcastReceiver

Comment: Try changing `getActivity(ctx, 1, listener, 0);` to `getActivity(ctx, 0, listener, 0);`. Just noticed your notification id is 0.

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
      RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(c
            .getPackageName(), R.layout.notification_custom);
 contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.buttonNotificationAccept, "Ok");
  contentView.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.buttonNotificationAccept,
                resultPendingIntent);
```